# InvokeHttp processor showing invalid

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using Apache Nifi using Docker image that i downloaded.
I am trying to configure a REST API "POST" for login using InvokeHttp processor.
I have configured all necessary steps in the configuration but still the processor shows "invalid".
Can you please help identify the issue. Here are my steps

[image: step 1]
[image: step 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you close the configuration dialog and hover the mouse over the "⚠️" icon on that processor, you will see a popup which enumerates the issues to be resolved. For the `InvokeHTTP` processor, it's likely that you have not specified a destination for all relationships -- you probably want a destination for `Response` (the response from the external web service), and possibly `Retry` and `Failure`. For any relationships you do not care about (`Original`, `No Retry`, etc.), you can "auto-terminate" those relationships from the "Settings" tab of the processor configuration dialog.

You can always see the required relationships from the Settings tab or by looking at the processor documentation (available online or embedded in the application by right clicking the processor and selecting "View Usage" from the context menu).

Comment: Thank You Andy, that does help. I had to actually either tick all the auto-terminate options or map to a processor.

Comment: But where i am stuck now is all the GET calls work fine. For the post i am not seeing any output. The Tasks/Time is showing increasing but In, Read/Write, Out are all showing 0. In view data provenance of POST processor, i dont see any data. How to debug what is happening in the POST processor. Also do i necessarily need to provide anything in the "Attributes to send"? i have tried empty and also tried putting "Authorization grant_type" as 2 dynamic attributes that i created and can be seen in my original screenshot.

Comment: Be sure that you are directing the `Response` connection to the correct follow-on processor (e.g. `LogAttribute`), and then stop the `LogAttribute` processor and right-click on the connection to `List Queue`. You can examine the individual flowfiles for the attributes and content sent back by the HTTP response to the POST request. Compare this with the output of `curl -X POST https://external.service.tld` for example.

Comment: Thank You Andy! i guess i made it work by adding a generate flow file processor before the InvokeHTTP processor and passed grant_type attribute from GenerateFlow File to InvokeHttp and it worked. I just want to know is this the only approach. Why cant i define the grant_type=client_credentials and pass as a body attribute in the InvokeHttp processor itself and pass to the POST like i have shown in my original screenshot. Do i have to put the GenerateFlowFile first?

Comment: Defining a dynamic property on `InvokeHTTP` will be treated as an HTTP header, so that would be sent as a header.

Comment: So what i am getting is that dynamic properties can be only used as Header properties and for any data that you need to send in BODY of Post it has to come from a processor before InvokeHttp?